# com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client version compatibility with spring boot 3.x

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, netflix-dgs

I am currently using com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client version 4.9.15. This worked well with spring boot 2.6.6.
On upgrading  to spring boot 3.x specifically 3.1.3 I am seeing few failures (If required I can add more details about this).

So I upgraded dgs client -  com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client  to 7.6.0. After upgrade, few things are working but other things are failing.

So in general, I want to know if there is a compatibly matrix between dgs framework specifically  **graphql-dgs-client**  and spring boot 3.0.  specifically 3.1.3.  Could some one share any details on the range of dgs clients that are compatible with spring boot 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it on [git](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/blob/v8.0.0-rc.1/graphql-dgs-client/dependencies.lock) by the tag release version, even the newest version (8.0.0-rc1) is supporting spring boot 3.0.8. Also we can get rid of versioning management by using [BOM](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/platform-bom/). Hope it helps.